# PHP conf file permissions

Tags: php, file-permissions

Having this strtucture in a PHP proyect:

```
htdocs/
    project_name/
        conf/
            db_info.xml
        html/
            index.php
```

index.php is reading db_info.xml

The owner and group of this project is and user created for it.

DOCUMENT_ROOT is htdocs/project_name/html/

Is insecure to set 644 the file with the DB info and credentials (db_info.xml)?

Read permision for all could be a security issue or let folder named 'conf' out of the DOCUMENT_ROOT shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Some information about your host/server wouldn't go amiss.

Answer (score 2):

I personally think that you don't need to give a read permission to all user, so don't give them.

> Read permision for all could be a security issue or let folder named 'conf' out of the DOCUMENT_ROOT shouldn't be a problem?

This is a must, if not anyone can read your databse if the file has got a 644 permission.

Using a .xml as a "database" it's not the best security solution anyway, use this solution only if you can't do anything else. Remember to use a strong hashing algorithm (bcrypt or argon2) with a salt

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your web server configuration - if you don't allow the web server to read and serve the `conf` directory publicly - should not be a problem. But generaly you should consider moving the configs out of a public folder.

Comment: Agreed.  the `conf` directory should be at the same directory level as the `htdocs` directory.  Hopefully his server will permit it.

Comment: @JBH should be at the same level?  Surely it's a matter of taste.  We don't even know which directory is the OP's 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm assuming `htdocs` is document root as it's a common name for it.

Comment: @JBH DOCUMENT_ROOT for this project is htdocs/html, there is various projects in htdocs. This could change your opinion?

Comment: Absolutely!  If document root is htdocs/html (i.e., the `html` folder), then the `conf` folder isn't public (from the point of view of port 80) and the only thing you may have to worry about are other users of the same disk resource.  In that case, @Riccardo Bonafede's answer is also useful.  Make sure the permissions don't allow other users (people who can actually login to the computer) access.  Do this and you're golden.